# How do I bind a Display Value of an Angular-Material Select field to ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I'm pretty new to the Angular development scene and have started with a Simple Taxi Booking Form. I append a Material-Select field with an Array with 2 properties like that:

```
{value: 24, view: '1010 - Vienna'}
```

that works well but when I submit the form and check the console.log field zip is equal to 24. How can I achieve, that ngModel binds to the view property of my dropdown?

Thank you very much!

**Expected Behavior:**

- When I submit the Form via onSubmit(), property zip of the form object should output "1010 - Innere Stadt" and not 24

I want to include that in the Form object ngForm has created, then I could directly send it to my Express API to store it in a Database. Image attached below

[Image to Form Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pitcb.png)

**app.component.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">

<mat-select placeholder="Postleitzahl" [(ngModel)]="zipValue" name="zip">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let z of zip" [value]="z.value" >{{z.view}} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-de',
  templateUrl: './form-de.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-de.component.css']
})


export class FormDeComponent {

zip = [
    { view: '1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24 },
    { view: '1020 - Leopoldstadt', value: 25 },
]

 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: ngModel is used to maintain data values of importance. If the 'view' is what you want, change your inModel to zipView rather than zipValue.

Comment: Hi @David I think you want to get selected `zip` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following change in the component -
Have a variable `zipValue`. Set it’s initial value to one of you `zip` array values [it is also fine to have undefined] -

```
export class FormDeComponent {

zipValue;

zip = [
    { view: '1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24 },
    { view: '1020 - Leopoldstadt', value: 25 },
]

ngOnItit() {

}

 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value.zip);
    console.log(this.zipValue);//you should see mat-select selected value; which would be an object.
  }
}
```

In template make the following change-

**EDIT 1 -** Use z.view in mat-option like this [This change is for - when you were needed `"view"` in zip

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let z of zip" [value]="z.view" >{{z.view}} 
    </mat-option>
```

**EDIT 2 -** Use z in mat-option like this [This change is for - when you need both `view and value` in zip; This is the same as my very first solution]

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let z of zip" [value]="z" >{{z.view}} 
    </mat-option>
```

In **"Edit 2"** on click of button, `console.log(form.value.zip);` will return `{view: '1010 - Innere Stadt', value: 24}` which has both value and view. While user will see the `"view"` in Mat-Select. **This is the standard way to implement Mat-Select.**

see the following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvjpxq?file=app/select-overview-example.ts

If you still want `form.zip.value` to return `"1010 - Innere Stadt"` and you want `"value"` then **"EDIT 1"** is the solution and then you will have to find that object in your zip array like this -

```
const foundZip = this.zip.find(z => z.view === form.value.zip)
```

Comment: @David See my edited answer as per your edited question.